# windows 10 context-menu NEW MENU items disappear

Tags: windows, contextmenu, regedit, windows-10-desktop

for strange reason:
when I open context menu in [C:] there Empty list.
when I open I [D:] all exist as should.

screenshot below
[image]

I need some help in equalizing [C:] NEW context menu to be equal to [D:] ?

many Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

According to [this question on technet.microsoft.com](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b3551fb8-1827-4d34-9661-03757d67b25d/why-there-is-only-quotnew-folderquot-option-when-i-right-click-on-quotwindowssystem32quot?forum=winserverGP), the logged on user is allowed to create folders in `c:\` drive root folder, but user has no rights to create files there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  
seems so.
on my other PC this NEW menu actual appears in c: without any restriction. 
so I guess there should be some work around to equalizing there appearance